# MySQL limit parameters relative to a row value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `boxes` table with a `box_size` column.
I want to fetch rows with a total size of 16.
How should I do this?

For example:

- fetch 16 rows with `box_size = 1`
- or two rows with `box_size = 4` and 4 rows with `box_size = 2`
- etc

EDIT:

I have this select query now:

```
select * from `boxes` order by `boxes`.`box_size` DESC, `date` DESC
```

So, if we had only rows with `box_size = 1` I would needed `LIMIT 0, 16` and if I had all rows with `box_size = 4` I would needed `LIMIT 0, 4`.

BUT every row has it's own box_size so I can't have an specific limit number, it should be calculated relative to fetched box_size value.

Comment: `E_QUESTION_HAS_TOO_MUCH_BOXES_BUT_NO_CLARITY`

Comment: @Simon_eQ sorry, I used an example for clarification.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to set a total number, like an `area` and fetch MySQL records that could fit in that area, right? Is there any rule on which records should MySQL select to cover your desired area?

Comment: So, if you need a total 15, you would accept three `box_size = 4`, 1 `box_size = 2` and 1 `box_size = 1`, right?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos YES exactly, but I dont need calculation for this, I have a 4 * 4 area and I have 4, 2 and 1 sized boxes.

Comment: So, it should just fetch random records (boxes) that fill up an area? I would love to see this solved.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos no, I have an ORDER BY, see my edit. Larger boxes are fetched first.

Comment: Found some possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976959/mysql-limit-by-sum and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839704/sum-until-certain-point-mysql

Comment: @Webinan I just updated my answer with a query that will retrieve appropriate boxes from biggest to smallest, check it out!

Comment: in you comments you mentioned that you need to fill an area of 4x4, does it not mean that only 1 box of box_size=4 can fill it ?

Comment: @nasirbest no, as I said as an example, 4 boxes of box_size=4 is needed (4x4=16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your data picked from **smallest to biggest** boxes, then this will help you:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, @sum:=@sum + box_size total_size FROM boxes
  JOIN ( SELECT @sum := 0 ) xa
  ORDER BY box_size
) t
WHERE total_size <= 16;
```

The nested query will go through all the boxes from the smallest to the biggest, and store `box_size` of the current box added up to sum of `box_size` of all the previous boxes, then the main query will return all boxes for which the sum is lower than or equal to 16;

If you need to go from **biggest to smallest** boxes, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
     *,
     @potential_total := @sum + box_size,
     @potential_total <= 16 as is_valid,
     @sum := IF( @potential_total <= 16, @potential_total, @sum) total_size
  FROM boxes
  JOIN ( SELECT @sum := 0 ) xa
  ORDER BY box_size DESC
) t
WHERE total_size <= 16 and is_valid = true;
```

I just tested the above example and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for but you could do the following queries:

```
 SELECT * FROM `boxes` WHERE `box_size` = 1 LIMIT 16; #returns 16 boxes of box_size 1
 SELECT * FROM `boxes` WHERE `box_size` = 4 LIMIT 2; #returns 2 boxes of box_size 4
 SELECT * FROM `boxes` WHERE `box_size` = 2 LIMIT 4; #returns 4 boxes of box_size 2
```

Comment: no, I want mysql to start fetching rows until summation of box_size values reaches 16. no matter it is reached with 16*1 or 8*2 or 2*4+4*2 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can put a running total of the area in where clause to solve this problem,

```
SET @size_sum:=0;
SELECT @size_sum:=(@size_sum + POW(box_size,2)) as size_sum, box_size 
FROM table WHERE @size_sum <= 16;
```

NOTE: `POW` function is being used to calculate the area of a box